# How to move permanently a smoothcamera?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using SmoothCamera to move my camera, but how can i do to permanently move it?

I have to set X & Y when use camera.setCenter().

How can i do to on "onSceneTouchEvent", move, and stop the camera movement?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `camera.setCenterDirect(x, y)`. Is that what you're looking for?